# How do I create a simple module in Java?

Tags: java, java-module, java-17

I have a very simple library with classes in one package. As far as I know, it only depends on things in java.base. I added a module-info.java to the top level directory that exports this package.

e.g.

```
module org.foo.bar {
    exports org.foo.bar.pkgname;
}
```

I then just built a simple jar file with my classes and the module-info class.

Is that it, or is there more that I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's it, as long as your jar is organized as follows:

```
module-info.class
org
 foo
  bar
   pkgname
    X.class
    Y.class
```

A jar with a module-info.class at top level is a module.
You can check your module with:

```bash
jar --describe-module --file bar.jar
```

Comment: You also have to care to put the jar file into the module path rather than class path when launching an application.